# can't install VM using virt-install

Tags: virtualization, virt-manager, kvm-virtualization, virt-install

I use this command:

```
virt-install -r 1024 --vcpus=2 --accelerate --nographics -n test -f test.img --cdrom /iso/CentOS.iso
```

but I doesn't show the text based install:

```
boot: linux text
Loading vmlinuz.................................
Loading initrd.img..............................................................
................................................................................
...................................
Ready.ÿ
```

It hangs at `Ready.ÿ`

any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: If you use different kernel options at the boot prompt does that give the same result?

Comment: Thanks, how it that possible? (I use putty)

Comment: It's technically not hanging- it's just waiting for you to respond in the graphical terminal (vnc, really). What happens if you append `-x "console=ttyS0"` to the end of your creation command?

Comment: @qweet Thanks, it gives me this error: 'ERROR    --extra-args only work if specified with --location.'

Comment: what about `virt-install -r 1024 --vcpus=2 --accelerate --nographics -n test -f test.img -l /iso/CentOS.iso -x "console=ttyS0"` ?

Comment: sorry, it failed again: ERROR    Could not find an installable distribution at '/iso/CentOS.iso'
The location must be the root directory of an install tree.
Domain installation does not appear to have been successful.

Comment: why not simply use virt-manager instead of virt-install?

Comment: because when I use GUI virt-manager it always freezes and it's really slow. I wasted a lot of times working with virt-manager.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

--graphics none SHOULD work.

By default RHEL bootup grub chooses graphical install mode if adapter is present. To use text mode installation "text" or "askmethod" must be specified in kernel options i.e. grub and it doesn't matter do you have text console or not. It's impossible to specify kernel options at installation for virt-install. It's possible for normal bootup, but not cd:

--boot kernel=KERNEL,initrd=INITRD,kernel_args="console=/dev/ttyS0"

The best solution is to use PXE bootup - there you can have your own boot menu and settings, but again "--graphics none" should work, but looks like in some circumstances some guys are experiencing problems:
[KVM Guest installed from console. But how to get to the guest's console?](https://serverfault.com/questions/257962/kvm-guest-installed-from-console-but-how-to-get-to-the-guests-console)

Comment: Thanks, I haven't tried it yet but I hope it works.