# Ubuntu KVM virsh console domain connects, but does not load console

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, virt-install

I installed a copy of Ubuntu 17.04 using virt-install, on my server (non desktop).

```
sudo virt-install --connect qemu:///system -n wiki -r 4096 --vcpus=2 -f /dev/mapper/vgpool-wiki --network=bridge:br0  --nographics --accelerate --location /var/lib/libvirt/iso/ubuntu-17.04-server-amd64.iso --os-type=linux  --extra-args=‘console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8 serial'
```

However, when I run `virsh console wiki` it just returns

> Connected to domain wiki
>   Escape character is ^]

I am very new to Linux, but can't seem to find anything that I can understand that solves my problem! But I think it's to do with how I installed Ubuntu using virt-install, any hints at all please?

Comment: this can help you https://serverfault.com/questions/257962/kvm-guest-installed-from-console-but-how-to-get-to-the-guests-console

Comment: Press Enter. You should then get the login prompt.